# jaxws-maven-plugin fail to run wsimport (ErrorListener)

Tags: java, maven, wsimport

I am stuck since yesterday on this problem.
I am using Maven 2 on Windows:

```
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 20:16:01+0100)
```

And in my POM I use the plugin `jaxws-maven-plugin` as this:

```xml
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>wsimport</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <wsdlFiles>
                <wsdlFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/MyService.wsdl
                </wsdlFile>
            </wsdlFiles>
            <packageName>my.package.name</packageName>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

When I run `mvn compile` I get the following error :

```
[INFO] jaxws:wsimport args: [-keep, -s, D:\myService\target\generated-sources\wsimport, -Xnocompile, -p, my.service.name, file:/D:/myService/src/main/resources/MyService.wsdl]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error executing: wsimport [-keep, -s, D:\myService\target\generated-sources\wsimport, -Xnocompile, -p, my.service.name, file:/D:/myService/src/main/resources/MyService.wsdl]

Embedded error: com/sun/tools/xjc/api/ErrorListener
com.sun.tools.xjc.api.ErrorListener
```

I tried :

- Adding a Windows env variable `MAVEN_OPT` with value `-Xmx768M -Xms768M -XX:PermSize=256m`
- To launch `wsimport` myself, and it is working :

  ```
  wsimport -keep -s D:\myService\target\generated-sources\wsimport -Xnocompile -p my.service.name file:/D:/myService/src/main/resources/MyService.wsdl
  ```

So anyone knows what could mean:

```
Embedded error: com/sun/tools/xjc/api/ErrorListener

com.sun.tools.xjc.api.ErrorListener
```

Comment: It is linked to this error : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145021/jaxws-maven-plugin-lifecycleexecutionexception?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding verbose logging for Maven helped me: `mvn -X compile`.

I had in fact a :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/xjc/api/ErrorListener
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
```

It is because one of my dependencies is not in the classpath.

Comment: What dependency have you added to your project?

Answer (score 5):

In case of

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/xjc/api/ErrorListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.Invoker.main(Invoker.java:72)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.xjc.api.ErrorListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 16 more
```

it could be that you are using a JRE instead of a JDK as project (or default) Eclipse JRE

Reference: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-consuming-web-service/issues/15#issuecomment-314018799